# Calling a polymorphic method that uses generics in java

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I'm in Java generics hell! What is the right way to do this:

```
interface Validator<T extends ParentThing> {
  void validate(T item);
}

class ValidatorImplOne implements Validator<ChildThingOne> {
  @Override
  public void validate(ChildThingOne thing1) {
    // whatever
  }
}

class ValidatorImplTwo implements Validator<ChildThingTwo> {
  @Override
  public void validate(ChildThingTwo thing2) {
    // whatever
  }
}

// Initialize this with string to ValidatorImplOne or ValidatorImplTwo instances
Map<String, Validator<? extends ParentThing>> VALIDATORS = ... 

public static void validate(String s, ParentThing thing) {
  Validator<? extends ParentThing> validator = VALIDATORS.get(s);

  // Does not compile! Complains that thing is not the right type.
  validator.validate(thing);
}
```

Even Eclipse auto-complete tells me that validate should take a ParentThing parameter but the compiler still complains if I pass a ParentThing. :(

This will work if I cast or remove generics but I want to know how to do this the "right" way without compiler warnings.

Comment: What are the string keys you are using? Do they somehow represent the validator implementations?

Comment: There's no way you can do this without unchecked casts. The compiler can't possibly guarantee that the validator stored under the given string key is able to validate the given ParentThing.

Comment: Ask yourself a question. What prevents `public void validate(ChildThingOne thing1)` be called with `ParentThing` that is instance of `ChildThingTwo` when `validator.validate(thing);` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the behavior you want from the compiler.

The code you've given isn't type-safe, so it makes sense that the compiler would require you to do a typecast.

This is because each of your `validate` methods takes a specific subclass of `ParentThing`. For example, in the `ChildThingOne` validator, the object you pass into the validate method must be assignable from `ChildThingOne`. When you have an instance of `Validator<? extends ParentThing>`, the compiler doesn't know what the actual type `validate` expects.

More generally, the compiler cannot guarantee that the `ParentThing` you pass to `validate` is assignable as a specific subtype of `ParentThing`.

You'll find that the code `validator.validate(new ChildThingOne())` has the same compiler error.

This can be seen in a simple example based on yours:

```
public static void validate(String s, ParentThing thing) {
    Validator<? extends ParentThing> validator = new ValidatorImplOne(); //? extends ParentThing means an unknown, but SPECIFIC, implementation of ParentThing
    
    validator.validate(new ChildThingOne()); //cannot compile
    //The compiler doesn't know if ChildThingOne is the actual type validator wants
}
```

To do this with generics, you'd have to use classes that extended `Validator<ParentThing>`. The other option, as you've pointed out, is to use typecast.

Here is an example of how the initial code can be modified to compile and work:

```
public static <T extends ParentThing> void validate(String s, T thing) {
    Validator<T> validator = (Validator<T>) VALIDATORS.get(s);
    
    validator.validate(thing);
}
```

Comment: The only thing I really understood was that what I was trying to do is just not possible, but I still don't really understand why. validator.validate(new ChildThingOne()) will still extend ParentThing which is what I said I wanted?

Comment: Calling `validator.validate(new ChildThingOne())` will not work because `validator` is of type `Validator<? extends ParentThing>`. `? extends ParentThing` means that the validator expects a **specific** class that extends `ParentThing`. However, by using the wildcard, `?`, the you are telling the compiler you don't know which specific class `validator` expects. Thus the compiler has no way to know if any class you give it is correct. The key is that '?' doesn't mean "any class", but instead "unknown class".